# ip6tables conntrack module does not work

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ipv6, ip6tables

I'm trying to setup my device such that only it may initiate network connections other hosts. I.e, other hosts should not be able to initiate a connection with the device.

I've got ipv4 working:

```
root@kp2:/proc/net# iptables -L 
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
root@kp2:/proc/net# 

root@kp2:/proc/net# ping 192.168.21.4
PING 192.168.21.4 (192.168.21.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.21.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.119 ms
^C
```

As you see, I get the ping response back. However, I cannot get similar functionality with ipv6:

```
root@kp2:/proc/net# ip6tables -L 
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
root@kp2:/proc/net# ping6 2010::232
PING 2010::232(2010::232) 56 data bytes
^C
--- 2010::232 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1006ms
```

Just to show you that the host at the other end indeed exists, as soon as I permit all packets on the INPUT chain, I see the ping response:

```
root@kp2:/proc/net# ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT
root@kp2:/proc/net# ip6tables -L 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
root@kp2:/proc/net# ping6 2010::232
PING 2010::232(2010::232) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2010::232: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.214 ms
^C
--- 2010::232 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.214/0.214/0.214/0.000 ms
```

Why is it that I can get `ping` to work with ipv4 but not with ipv6 network?

Answer (score 0):

This rule does not seem to work for me.

```bsh
ip6tables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

However, I could get similar functionality with these three rules which seem to do the trick:

```bsh
ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p udp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Note however it accepts *all* icmp traffic, not just related ones.

Comment: If you block ICMP you are going to disrupt your network connectivity. Best to allow it if you want things to work. Of course it will work fine with your original rule.